# Laravel 7 throws error 255 upgrading from laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, installation, upgrade

I just tried to upgrade Laravel from v6 to v7, my php version is 7.3, i upgraded all dependencies as stated on laravel site, and removed conflicting packages, the upgrade seems to be completed but with the following error:

```
Generating optimized autoload files> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of App\Exceptions\Handler::report(Exception $exception) must be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::report(Throwable $e) in /var/www/html/virtuozzo-api/app/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 8
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Exceptions\Handler does not exist in /var/www/html/virtuozzo-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:803
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/virtuozzo-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(803): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\Exceptions\\...')
#1 /var/www/html/virtuozzo-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(681): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Exceptions\\...')
#2 /var/www/html/virtuozzo-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(787): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Exceptions\\...', Array, false)
#3 /var/www/html/virtuozzo-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(265): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('App\\Exceptions\\...', Array, false)
#4 /var/www/html/virtuozzo-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(799): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container\{cl in /var/www/html/virtuozzo-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 805
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

i have tried already deleting the vendor folder and installing again, also with composer dump autoload, and tried to clear laravel cache, but always get the same error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your [`app/Exceptions/Handler.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Exceptions/Handler.php) file: replace the `Exception` typehints with `Throwable` typehints.

As mentioned in the [Upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#symfony-5-related-upgrades).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the difference

[image: Laravel 7 app > Exception > Handler.php]

Here is the updated file,

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param Throwable $exception
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function report(Throwable $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Throwable $exception
     * @return Response
     *
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```